# How to compute encrypt and decrypt runtime for algorithm

Tags: java, rsa

I'm trying to implement an RSA algorithm using the following two function in Java:

```
time_one = 0    
private void encrypt()    
{   
    M = new BigInteger(64,random);   
    C = M.modPow(e,N);  
}  
time_encrypt = time_now-time_one  

time_two = 0   
private void decrypt()   
{   
    Mp = C.modPow(dp, p);   
    Mq = C.modPow(dq, q);   
    MM =    Mp.multiply(q).multiply(q.modInverse(p))).add(Mq.multiply(p).multiply(p.modInverse(q)))).mod(N);  
}  
time_decrypt = time_now-time_two
```

How can determine time `encrypt()` takes for data size 1kb and 2kb to 10 kb? How can I represent the different sizes of the data?

Does that method to calculate run-time good to compare speed runtime for `encrypt()` and `decrypt()`?

Answer (score 0):

You will see vastly different results once the JIT has kicked in. Generally what you should do is spin up the JVM by using encrypt/decrypt around 100k times WITHOUT metering them. This will allow the JIT to kick in and compile the necessary parts to native code AFTER this you can start your benchmarking by taking the starttime in nanoseconds via System.nanoTime(). Using this methodology will at least give you some insight as to the performance of your code. However, I will strongly advise you to go through the following presentation: http://www.azulsystems.com/presentations/art-of-java-benchmarking

And also follow some blogs where people who know what they are doing perform micro-benchmarks. Some of those are for example:

http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/adventures-with-atomiclong.html
or http://mentablog.soliveirajr.com/?s=benchmark

PS. Why do you need to implement RSA yourself? Generally in cryptography the guiding principle is - "Unless you are as good as Bruce Schenier or a world-renowned cryptographer don't try to invent new cryptographic algorithms, chances are they will be insecure". If it is for learning purposes then by all means go and do it.